# How to include header from a subdirectory, whose parent directory is specified using '-I' to "gcc"?

Tags: c, gcc, header-files, suppress-warnings

I am compiling a C source file with `-Wall` option. It is giving me

`abc.c: XX: warning: implicit declaration of function xyz()`

I found out that the prototype for the function `xyz` is in a header present in the following directory path (similar to this): `/root/parent1/parent2/include/sub_dir/`

While compiling it, I am specifying the path till `include/` directory using `-I` option.

So to include the required header file I did this:

`#include"sub_dir/header.h"`

But the warning didn't get suppressed.

I tried using `<..>` also: `#include<sub_dir/header.h>`

Is their any other way to suppress the warning besides specifying the path to `sub_dir` in `-I` option itself? What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

**UPDATE:**

The compilation command is:

`gcc -DDS_FOR_UNIX -DN_PLAT_UNIX -Wall -fPIC -I/home/mnishant/Work/include -I<more include paths>  -o CMakeFiles/lib/file1.c.o   -c /home/mnishant/Work/lib/file1.c`

Comment: should work, can you post entire command used to compile.

Comment: `#include "sub_dir/header.h"` would fail compilation if it wasn't found. Something else is going on.